# How to update database after clicking on html element?

Tags: flask, web-applications

In my flask application, I have a points column in the database, which is initialized to 0 on user registration. Now, I want to be able to update the points in database after clicking an html element.

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

```
@bp.route('/activity1')
@login_required
def activity1():
    return render_template('activity1.html', title='Activity 1')
```

Activity1.html has the point-generating html element

```
@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    ...
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user.points = 0
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        ...
```

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" class="w3-large" href="#tip4" onclick="getPoints()">...</a>

<script>
function getPoints(){
  points += 20; #How do i access the database.points in this case?
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the code correctly, but are you asking how to update the number of points from `activity1.html` in the last code snippet? That won't work, the HTML is rendered on the server and once presented to the browser, there's no link between the two.

If you need to pass some data to the template while rendering it, you have to pass it in the `render_template` call, e.g.

```
render_template('activity1.html', title='Activity 1', user=user)
```

Then you can access it in the template like this:

```
<script>
function getPoints(){
  points = {{ user.points|int }} + 20;
  // post to backend to update data in database (using jQuery)
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: {
        id: "{{ user.id }}",
        points: points
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'http://xxx/update_points',
      success: function (e) {
          // successful call
      },
      error: function(error) {
          // an error occured
      }
  });
}
</script>
```

If you then want to update the user points in the database, you'll have to make a request to the server, which will take care of this. On the server side in Flask, define a view to handle this request:

```
@bp.route('/update_points', methods=['POST'])
def update_points():
    data = request.get_json()
    # don't know exactly what's the model and how to get the 'user' instance
    user = User.get_user_by_id(data['id'])
    user.points = data['points']
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

Take it as an example code, I didn't test it and ommited quite a lot of details (e.g. how to get `user` instance in `update_points` etc.) Also, I might have missed what you are really asking for.